# Как разбить строку из латиницы и кириллицы посимвольно в массив?

Tags: php

Как разбить строку в массив или просто поэлементно взять каждый символ этой строки? Проблемы возникает в том, что строка состоит из букв кириллицы. Нужно вывести строку как массив (поэлементно). Кодировка стоит utf-8.

```
<?php

$word = 'слово';

$lng = iconv_strlen($word);   

for ($i = 0; $i < $lng; $i++){
    echo $word[$i];
}
```

Нужно чтобы и кириллица поддерживалась и латынь.

Comment: если имеется дело *только* с кириллицей, то можно использовать mb_substr  да и дело с концом

Comment: нет, нужно чтобы и кириллица поддерживалась и латынь.

Comment: изменять вопрос, в частности добавлять условия, когда Вам уже дали один или несколько ответов это плохая практика.

Comment: @Alex так а при чём тут латынь?

Comment: латинский алфавит

Comment: @ScreamingVoices копи паст, поправил.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Используйте [`preg_split`](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.preg-split.php) или [`preg_match_all`](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.preg-match-all.php)

```
$mbstring = 'Хей!';

// Путь 1
print_r(
  preg_split('//u', $mbstring, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY)
);

// Путь 2
preg_match_all('/./u', $mbstring, $matches);
print_r(
  $matches[0]
);
```

Comment: Спасибо, именно ваш вариант правилный !!! А именно вариант 1.

Answer (score 0):

```
function getArrRus($str) {
  $length = mb_strlen($str);
  $arrRus = [];

  for($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
    $arrRus[] = mb_substr($str, $i, 1);
  }

  return $arrRus;
}

var_dump(getArrRus('абв'));
```

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [Справке](/help/how-to-answer).